# Does somebody know if the Light themes will get overhauled for Natty?

Tags: 11.04, themes

I'm just curious to know if the Light themes will get overhauled for Natty since they jumped from being okay in Lucid to being awesome in Maverick.

Answer (score 4):

Currently the themes have the following changes from the maverick version from the changelog.

> - Ambiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc
>
>   - Removed style for IdoMessageDialog   *
>       Radiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc
>   - Removed style for IdoMessageDialog
> - apps/ubuntuone.rc: Move the Ubuntu
>     One-specific themeing for when
>     running under light-themes into the theme.  This impoves the
>     look of the Ubuntu One clients when running under other themes.
>     (LP: #715717)
> - Ambiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc,
>     Radiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc
>
>   - Set style for IdoMessageDialog used by incoming call notifications 
>       in empathy
> - New Ambiance properties for
>      and  added to
>     metacity theme files (for invisible window grip support).
>     These are read by libmetacity-private so that they can
>     be
>     exported by new functionality and picked up by
>     'unity-window-decorator' which was introduced in compiz-gnome
>     1:0.9.2.1+glibmainloop4. Partial solution to (LP: #160311).
> - Apply
>     Ambiance/.../metacity-theme-1.xml
>     changes to Radiance.   * Add Breaks:
>     metacity (<< 1:2.30.3-0ubuntu2) since
>     the introduction
>     of new parsing support will prevent backporting to maverick unless
>     the corresponding patch to Metacity is backported first.
> - Add symlinks so the themes work in
>     GTK3
> - Include cpu-freq among the panel
>     applets known to the Ambiance theme
>     (LP: #640096)

Comment: So in summary: they're not going to be overhauled but they are being tweaked.